# Создание динамического двумерного массива с++

Tags: c++, массивы

Как создать двумерный динамический массив из строк в с++?

```
char ***test = new char**[5];

for (int i = 0; i != 5; ++i) {
    *test[i] = new char[2];
}

for (int k = 0; k != 5; ++k) {
    for (int i = 0; i != 5; ++i) {
        test[k][i] = new char[255];
    }

}

test[0][1] = "232";
```

пытался сделать так, но "232" не присваивается (const char * не возможно присвоить char*)

Comment: Видимо, вы хотите скопировать строку `"232"` в `test[0][1]`? Тогда `strcpy(test[0][1], "232")`

Comment: Вместо всей этой [гимнастики с указателями](http://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer) можно было бы использовать `std::vector<std::string>` размера `5*2`.

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать и через указатели. Вот пример для квадратной матрицы:

```
#include <string>
...
int size = 0;
cin >> size;
string **mass = new string[size];
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
     mass[i] = new string[size];
...
delete []mass;
```

Comment: Вообще-то этот код содержит утечку памяти. Вы выделяете `size + 1` блок, а освобождаете только 1.