# Создание динамического двумерного массива

Tags: c++, c, массивы, динамические-массивы

К примеру у меня есть `char buffer[100][50]`. Я хочу тоже самое, только динамически выделяемое. Я запамятовал про `malloc` и прочее в том же духе, и уже не помню как это делается в старом дедовском С. Старожилы, помогите.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для создания массива, аналогичного

```
T arr[N][M]
```

но динамического делаем так:

```
T** arr = malloc(N*sizeof(T*));
for(int i = 0; i < M; ++i)
    arr[i] = malloc(M*sizeof(T));
```

Где `T` - нужный нам тип.

Освобождение памяти выполняется в обратном порядке:

```
for(int i = 0; i < M; ++i)
    free(arr[i]);
free(arr);
```

Еще один вариант - выделение одним большим куском, чтобы и освобождать один раз. При этом вначале хранятся указатели на строки, а затем - данные.

```
T** arr = malloc(N*(sizeof(T*)+M*sizeof(T)));
for(int i = 0, ofs = N*sizeof(T*); i < N; i++)
    arr[i] = (T*)((char*)arr + ofs + i*M*sizeof(T));
```

Или, что то же самое

```
T** arr = malloc(N*(sizeof(T*)+M*sizeof(T)));
for(int i = 0, ofs = N*sizeof(T*); i < N; i++, ofs += M*sizeof(T))
    arr[i] = (T*)((char*)arr + ofs);
```

или так

```
for(int i = N, ofs = N*sizeof(T*); i-->0; ofs += M*sizeof(T))
    arr[i] = (T*)((char*)arr + ofs);
```

Тогда освобождение памяти тоже выполняется один раз:

```
free(arr);
```

Если вы по недоразумению или неумению компилируете С как С++, допишите приведение типа перед `malloc` -

```
T** arr = (T**)malloc(N*sizeof(T*));
arr[i] = (T*)malloc(M*sizeof(T));
```

P.S. Обращение к элементам массива - как к функциям, передача в функцию - как тип `T**`.

P.P.S. И на всякий случай - не забываем, что после создания массива его элементы заполнены мусором!

И еще. Вот такой вариант кода, как приведено ниже, позволяет хранить размеры массива прямо в выделенном массиве (перед указателями). Проблема в том, что при этом из функции возвращается смещенный указатель, так что цена вопроса - в том, что удалять такой массив нужно только через свою функцию. Зато при передаче не нужны никакие дополнительные параметры :)

```
T** create(int N, int M)
{
    T** arr = (T**)malloc(2*sizeof(int)+N*(sizeof(T*)+M*sizeof(T)));
    *((int*)arr)   = N;
    *((int*)arr+1) = M;
    arr = (T**)((char*)arr+2*sizeof(int));

    for(int i = N, ofs = N*sizeof(T*);
        i-->0; ofs += M*sizeof(T))
        arr[i] = (T*)((char*)arr + ofs);

    return arr;
}

void kill(T** arr)
{
    free((char*)arr-2*sizeof(int));
}

int rows(T**arr)
{
    return *(int*)((char*)arr-2*sizeof(int));
}

int cols(T**arr)
{
    return *(int*)((char*)arr-sizeof(int));
}
```

Тут - https://ideone.com/ZHB1uW - пример использования.

Comment: Подставил вот так char** arr = malloc(rows * sizeof(char*)); И значение типа void* нельзя использовать для инициализации сущности char**. Мб что-то не так??

Comment: Не так - вы компилируете как C++, а не как С... Вы же просили в С, нет?

Comment: Значит я ввёл вас в заблуждение(не специально постановкой вопроса), да мне нужно скомпилировать как с++. Как можно исправить ваш вариант?

Comment: Я дописал в ответе на вопрос. Если ответ вас устроил - принимайте (птичка слева).

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно выделять память для матрицы, у которой размеры константы, то можно просто выделить память для матрицы и пользоваться.

```
char ( * bufferp )  [ 100 ] [ 50  ] =
  ( char ( * )  [ 100 ] [ 50  ] )
  malloc  ( sizeof  ( char [  100 ] [ 50  ] ) ) ;
( * bufferp ) [ 50  ] [ 25  ] = 'x' ;
free  ( bufferp ) ;
```

А если размеры матриц нефиксированы константными числами, то стандарт запрещает использовать тип с неизвестным количеством строк/столбцов и надо будет создавать вектор строк матрицы индивидуально.

```
char * * makematr ( int h , int w ) {
  // сама матрица с данными
  char * d = ( char * ) malloc ( sizeof  ( char  ) * w * h ) ;
  // вектор строк матрицы
  char * * r = ( char * * ) malloc  ( sizeof  ( char  * ) * h ) ;
  for ( int i = 0 ; i < h ; ++  i )
    r [ i ] = & d [ i * w ] ;
  return  r ; }

void freematr ( char * * m  ) {
  // удаляем матрицу с данными
  free  ( m [ 0 ] ) ;
  // удаляем вектор строк матрицы
  free  ( m ) ; }

int main  ( ) {
  char * * buffer2 = makematr ( 100 , 50  ) ;
  buffer2 [ 50 ] [ 25 ] = 'x' ;
  freematr  ( buffer2 ) ;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
// динамическое создание двумерного массива вещественных чисел
int sizeZ = 2;
int sizeY = 6;
int sizeX = 9;
int num = 0; // для заполнения динамического массива
int num2 = 0; // для заполнения динамического массива
// заполнение массива
cout << "=====================================================================" << endl;
int** dynMatrix = new int* [sizeY];
for (int** matrixPtr = dynMatrix; matrixPtr < dynMatrix + sizeY; ++matrixPtr)
{
    *matrixPtr = new int[sizeX];
    for (int* linePtr = *matrixPtr; linePtr < *matrixPtr + sizeX; ++linePtr)
    {
        *linePtr = ++num;
    }

}
// вывод массива
cout << "=====================================================================" << endl;
for (int** matrixPtr = dynMatrix; matrixPtr < dynMatrix + sizeY; ++matrixPtr)
{
    for (int* linePtr = *matrixPtr; linePtr < *matrixPtr + sizeX; ++linePtr)
    {
        cout << setw(4) << setprecision(2) << *linePtr << "   ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}


cout << "=====================================================================" << endl;
int** dynMatrix2 = new int* [sizeY];
for (int** matrixPtr2 = dynMatrix2; matrixPtr2 < dynMatrix2 + sizeY; ++matrixPtr2)
{
    *matrixPtr2 = new int[sizeX];
    for (int* linePtr2 = *matrixPtr2; linePtr2 < *matrixPtr2 + sizeX; ++linePtr2)
    {
        *linePtr2 = ++num2+100;
    }

}
// вывод массива
cout << "=====================================================================" << endl;
for (int** matrixPtr2 = dynMatrix2; matrixPtr2 < dynMatrix2 + sizeY; ++matrixPtr2)
{
    for (int* linePtr2 = *matrixPtr2; linePtr2 < *matrixPtr2 + sizeX; ++linePtr2)
    {
        cout << setw(4) << setprecision(2) << *linePtr2 << "   ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

cout << "=====================================================================" << endl;
for (int** matrixPtr2 = dynMatrix2, **matrixPtr = dynMatrix; matrixPtr2 < dynMatrix2 + sizeY, matrixPtr < dynMatrix + sizeY; ++matrixPtr2, ++matrixPtr)
{
    for (int* linePtr2 = *matrixPtr2, *linePtr = *matrixPtr; linePtr2 < *matrixPtr2 + sizeX, linePtr < *matrixPtr + sizeX; ++linePtr2, ++linePtr)
    {
        (*linePtr2) = (*linePtr);
    }
    
}
cout << "=====================================================================" << endl;


cout << "=====================================================================" << endl;

// вывод массива
cout << "=====================================================================" << endl;
for (int** matrixPtr2 = dynMatrix2; matrixPtr2 < dynMatrix2 + sizeY; ++matrixPtr2)
{
    for (int* linePtr2 = *matrixPtr2; linePtr2 < *matrixPtr2 + sizeX; ++linePtr2)
    {
        cout << setw(4) << setprecision(2) << *linePtr2 << "   ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}



cout << "=====================================================================" << endl;


// удаление двумерного динамического массива
for (int** matrixPtr = dynMatrix; matrixPtr < dynMatrix + sizeY; ++matrixPtr)
{
    delete[] * matrixPtr;
}
delete[] dynMatrix;


cout << "=====================================================================" << endl;

cout << "DEL:1 array" << endl;

// удаление двумерного динамического массива
for (int** matrixPtr2 = dynMatrix2; matrixPtr2 < dynMatrix2 + sizeY; ++matrixPtr2)
{
    delete[] * matrixPtr2;
}
delete[] dynMatrix2;

cout << "DEL:2 array" << endl;


system("pause"); // для Visual Studio
return 0;
```

Comment: вместо отправки одного и того же ответа к нескольким вопросам ([1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1138287), [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/912985), [3](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/62781), [4](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1488675)) лучше было бы отправить только один и проголосовать за закрытие остальных вопросов как дубликатов.