# Исключение обработки ввода с использованием динамического массива на языке C

Tags: c, массивы, visual-studio, память

Столкнулся с проблемой обработки вводимых данных с использованием двумерного динамического массива. При вводе корректного значения в строке 55:

```
readCount = scanf_s("%d", &array[i][j]);
```

выскакивает сообщение:

*Вызвано исключение по адресу 0x7BF49D4E (ucrtbased.dll) в laba5_3.exe: 0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при записи по адресу 0xCDCDCDCD.*

Гуглил эту проблему, но ничего конкретного по С так и не нашел. Прошу помочь с решением данной проблемы.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>

int ClearStdin()
{
    int rv = 1;
    int ch;
    while (1) {
        ch = getchar();
        if (ch == '\n' || ch == EOF) {
            break;
        } 
        rv = 0;
    }
    return rv;
}

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    int n, m, countzero = 0, countneg = 0, countpos = 0, readCount, isEmpty;
    int **array;

    printf("Введите размерность (n) и (m) массива \n");

    //Проверка n
    while (1) {
        readCount = scanf_s("%d", &n);
        isEmpty = ClearStdin();
        if (readCount == 1 && isEmpty != 0 && n > 0) {
            break;
        }
        printf("Неверный формат числа. Введите целое положительное число\n");
    }
    //Проверка m
    while (1) {
        readCount = scanf_s("%d", &m);
        isEmpty = ClearStdin();
        if (readCount == 1 && isEmpty != 0 && m > 0) {
            break;
        }
        printf("Неверный формат числа. Введите целое положительное число\n");
    }

    array = (int*)malloc(n * m * sizeof(int));

    //Ввод элементов матрицы
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            printf("Введите целый элемент в формате (a,b) [%d,%d]\n", i, j);
            //Проверка
            while (1) {
                readCount = scanf_s("%d", &array[i][j]);
                isEmpty = ClearStdin();
                if (readCount == 1 && isEmpty != 0) {
                    break;
                }
                printf("Неверный формат числа. Введите целое положительное число\n");
            }
        }
    }
    //Вывод матрицы
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
            printf("%d ", array[i][j]);
        printf("\n");

    }

    //Поиск отрицательных,положительных и нулей
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            if (array[i][j] < 0) {
                countneg++;
            }
            else if (array[i][j] == 0) {
                countzero++;
            }
            else if (array[i][j] > 0) {
                countpos++;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("Колво положительных :%d\nКолво нулей :%d\nКолво отрицательных :%d", countpos, countzero, countneg);

    free(array);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/main_function + https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/13970074

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Двумерный динамический массив A создается следующим образом:

```
int **A = (int **)malloc(N*sizeof(int *));
for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
A[i] = (int *)malloc(M*sizeof(int));
}
```

, где переменные N и M - строки и стобцы соответственно.

Касательно функциональности, дальше всё стандартно: объявление счетчиков i и j для строк и столбцов соответственно.

Очистка памяти для данного массива выглядит таким образом:

```
for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
free(A[i]);
}
free(A);
```

Итоговый вариант кода:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int ClearStdin()
{
    int rv = 1;
    int ch;
    while (1) {
        ch = getchar();
        if (ch == '\n' || ch == EOF) {
            break;
        }
        rv = 0;
    }
    return rv;
}

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

    int N, M;
    int readCount, isEmpty;

    printf_s("Введите размерность N: "); //ввод N
    while (1) {
        readCount = scanf_s("%d", &N);
        isEmpty = ClearStdin();
        if (readCount == 1 && isEmpty != 0 && N > 0) {
            break;
        }
        printf("Неверный формат числа. Введите целое положительное число\n");
    }

    printf_s("Введите размерность M: "); //ввод M
    while (1) {
        readCount = scanf_s("%d", &M);
        isEmpty = ClearStdin();
        if (readCount == 1 && isEmpty != 0 && M > 0) {
            break;
        }
        printf("Неверный формат числа. Введите целое положительное число\n");
    }

    int** A = (int**)malloc(N * sizeof(int*));
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        A[i] = (int*)malloc(M * sizeof(int));
    }
    //создание динамической матрицы N*M


    int i, j;

    for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < M; j++) {
            printf_s("A[%d][%d] = ", i + 1, j + 1);
            //scanf_s("%d", &A[i][j]);
            while (1) {
                readCount = scanf_s("%d", &A[i][j]);
                isEmpty = ClearStdin();
                if (readCount == 1 && isEmpty != 0) {
                    break;
                }
                printf("Неверный формат числа. Введите целое положительное число\n");
            }
        }
    //заполнение матрицы с клавиатуры
    
    int countneg = 0, countzero = 0, countpos = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < M; j++) {
            if (A[i][j] < 0) {
                countneg++;
            }
            else if (A[i][j] == 0) {
                countzero++;
            }
            else if (A[i][j] > 0) {
                countpos++;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("Кол-во положительных :%d\nКол-во нулей :%d\nКол-во отрицательных :%d", countpos, countzero, countneg);


    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        free(A[i]);
    }
    free(A);
    // очистка памяти

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Э нет, это так не работает...

Раз вы объявили

```
int **array;
```

то уже никаких

```
array = (int*)malloc(n * m * sizeof(int));
```

Компилятор же не знает, как обратиться к `array[i][j]`.

Так что лучше всего

```
array = malloc(n * sizeof(int*));
for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    array[i] = malloc(m*sizeof(int));
```

Вот тогда

```
array[i][j]
```

имеет смысл...

Ну, и не забывайте потом освобождать память тоже - сначала в цикле, потом общий указатель.

А вообще посмотрите [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1138290/195342) - там это все разобрано подробно...

P.S. Еще - как примечание - в С приведение результата `malloc()` к типу вашего указателя не нужно. Если компилятор ругается - значит, вы компилируете код не как С, а как С++.

Answer (score 1):

Если `n` это количество строк матрицы, то для того способа ее представления (один кусок памяти), что вы используете, нельзя писать `array[i][j]` для доступа к ее элементам.

Объявить переменную для  такой матрицы целых чисел придется вот так `int *array` (указатель на целые, а не указатель на указатель, как у вас написано).

Тогда для доступа к элементу [i][j] надо писать `array[i * n + j]`.

И для ввода данных получится `scanf("%d" &array[i * n + j])` или `scanf("%d", array + i * n + j)`.

Кстати, память под матррицу `array = (int*)malloc(n * m * sizeof(int));` вы выделили правильно.