# Двумерный динамический массив на C

Tags: c, массивы, dynamic

В чем может быть ошибка создания массива? Требуется вычислить сумму элементов в каждой строке и в каждом столбце.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
 
int main (void)
{
  int n, s, m;
  scanf ("%i%i", &n, &m);
  int (*arr)[m];
  arr = malloc(sizeof(*arr) * n);   // COLS is in the `sizeof`
  arr = malloc(sizeof(int[n][m]));
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
      for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
    {
        scanf ("%i", &arr[i][j]);
    }
    }
 
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
      int sum = 0;
      for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
    {
      sum += arr[i][j];
    }
    printf ("%i ", sum);
    }
    printf ("\n");
  for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
    {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
         sum += arr[i][j];
        }
        printf ("%i ", sum);
    }
    printf ("\n\n");
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
      for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
    {
        printf ("%i ", arr[i][j]);
    }
        printf ("\n");
    }
     
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
      free (arr);
    }
}
```

Comment: Лучше не используй VLA.

Comment: См. [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1138290/195342)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
arr = malloc(sizeof(*arr) * n);   // COLS is in the `sizeof`
arr = malloc(sizeof(int[n][m]));
```

выделили память 2 раза и оба раза одной и той же переменной присвоили? хитро :)

в общем если вы создаёте динамически двухмерный массив - т.е. массив массивов, то

1. выделите память под `n` строк
2. пройдитесь по всему массиву и выделите память для каждой строки под `m` столбцов

ну или выделите память под одномерный массив размером `m x n` но тогда и индексацию полностью берите на себя и работайте как с одномерным массивом

примерный код:

```
int** arr = 0;

const int cols = 10;
const int rows = 20;

arr = malloc(cols * sizeof(int*));

for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
    arr[i] = malloc(rows * sizeof(int));
}

arr[8][19] = 123;
```

на счет голого C не уверен - вроде в цикле нельзя было задавать переменную и надо было снаружи указать `int i;`

Comment: Вот так?  int *arr;
  arr = (int*)malloc(n * sizeof(int));

Comment: Чтобы по 2 способу написать так     int *arr;
    arr = (int*)malloc(n * m * sizeof(int));   ? а то не совсем понимаю как оформить

Comment: добавил в ответе код - вроде так должно быть на голом C

Answer (score 1):

Если делать массив в стеке то как всегда :

```
int arr[n][m] ;
arr[i][j] = 7;
```

А если стек будет выделен в куче то так :

```
int ( * arrp ) [n][m] = malloc(sizeof(int[n][m]));
(*arrp)[i][j] = 7;
free(arrp);
```

Но если вы захотите передать адрес этого массива другой функции, то придётся возится с преобразованиями типов. Некоторые программисты делают как вектор векторов. Тогда возится с типами не надо.

```
int * * arrpp = malloc (sizeof(int*)*n);
for (int i=0;i<n;++i)
  arrpp[i] = malloc(sizeof(int)*m);
arrpp[i][j] = 7;
for (int i=0;i<n;++i)
  free(arrpp[i]);
free(arrpp);
```

Всё на любителя.