# c++ программирование

Tags: c++

С двумерным массивом, состоящим из n вещественных элементов, выполнить следующее: преобразовать массив, удалив из него одинаковые элементы. Освободившиеся в конце массива элементы заполнить звездочками (*).
Есть набросок кода, но он удаляет только копии, а сам элемент нет.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int size, m, i;
    cin >> size;
    float* arr = new float[size];
    for (m = 0; m < size; m++) {
        cin >> arr[m];
    }
    for (m = 0; m < size; m++) {
        cout << arr[m] << endl;
        for (i = m + 1; i < size; i++) {
            if (arr[m] == arr[i]) {
                for (int k = i; k < size - 1; k++) {
                    arr[k] = arr[k + 1];
                }
                size--;
            
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Массив создавать динамически или нет?

Comment: нужно динамический

Comment: Вот тут - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1138287/195342 - как его создавать. Когда создадите - напишите программу как для обычного массива, с синтаксисом `array[][]`, ну, а когда у вас будет уже набросан код - тогда будет о чем поговорить, как его изменить...

Comment: Проблема заключается в удалении всех одинаковых элементов, у меня получается удалить только все копии элемента, но сам элемент не получается удалить

Comment: Элементы вещественного массива  заполнить звёздочками????

Comment: Ну как я понял задание, можно юзать строку, а вот пользователь будет вводить как-бы вещественные числа