# Отсортировать методом обмена четные столбцы матрицы по возрастанию, нечетные - по убыванию

Tags: c, массивы, алгоритм, память, матрицы

Нужно отсортировать методом обмена четные столбцы матрицы по возрастанию, нечетные - по убыванию. Этот код не работает, заменяя все элементы столбца последним элементом. Не могу найти, где ошибка в алгоритме.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int t=0;
    int N=0;
    int A[N][N];
    do{  printf("Введите длинну рядка и столбца:\n");
        scanf("%d", &N);
    }while(N<1 || N>50);
    
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
        printf("\n");
        for(int j=0; j<N; j++){
            A[i][j] = rand() % 100;
            printf("\t%2.0d", A[i][j]);
            }}
    for(int j=0;j<N;j++){
        if (j%2==1){
        for(int k=N-1;k>0;k--){
        for(int i=0;i<k;i++){
            if(A[i][j]<A[i+1][j]){
                t=A[i][j];
                A[i][j]=A[i+1][j];
                A[i+1][j]=t;
            }
        }
        }}
        if (j%2==0){
        for(int k=N-1;k>0;k--){
            for(int i=0;i<k;i++){
                if(A[i][j]>A[i+1][j]){
                    t=A[i][j];
                    A[i][j]=A[i+1][j];
                    A[i+1][j]=t;
                }
            }
        }
        }}
    printf("\n");
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
        printf("\n");
        for(int j=0; j<N; j++){
            printf("\t%2.0d", A[i][j]);
            }}
}
```

Comment: После вот этого - `int N=0; int A[N][N];` - даже странно, что она вообще запускается :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы выделяете память неверно (а еще используете неверный спецификатор, но тут позже) -

```
int N=0;
int A[N][N];
```

В лучшем случае вы попытались выделить массив нулевого размера. Как совет - или используйте массив, скажем, `int A[50][50]` - у вас это предельный размер, или перенесите объявление массива как есть (раз ваш компилятор позволяет VLA) в строку **после** ввода `N`

```
} while(N<1 || N>50);

int A[N][N];
```

или выделяйте его динамически (см., например, [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1138290/195342)). Все будет работать.

И еще - вы работаете с целыми числами, а для них указывать `.0` в спецификаторе вывода

```
printf("\t%2.0d", A[i][j]);
```

просто бессмысленно. Достаточно `%2d`.

Еще, не сочтите за вредность, но по-русски - "по возрастанию", "по убыванию" или "в порядке возрастания/убывания".

Comment: Судя по всему, «за возрастанием» — калька с украинского.

Comment: @VladD Так воно i є...  https://ibb.co/q7PVhRy :-)

Comment: Знаю, я теж з Києва і розумію українську :-)

Comment: "Распространенье наше по планете отчетливей заметно вдалеке..."