# Объявление глобального массива внутри if язык C

Tags: c, массивы

есть следующий код:

```
printf("Введите размер первой матрицы. Если размер неизвестен, введите 0");
scanf ("%d", &n1);
if (n1)
{
    scanf ("%d", &m1);
    static int first_matrix[n1][m1];
}
else 
{
    static int first_matrix[100][100];
}
```

Далее происходит запись данного массива:

```
for (i=0; i<n1; i++) 
{
    for (j=0; j<m1; j++)
    scanf ("%d", &first_matrix[i][j]);
}
```

Компилятор выдает ошибку

> error: ‘first_matrix’ undeclared

т.к. массив объявляется внутри if, соответственно, насколько я понимаю, при выходе из if он пропадает. Однако я никак не могу придумать, как сделать по-другому, и при этом не знаю, как объявить массив глобально, что б он не пропал.
Если есть возможность данный код переделать, либо объявить массив, который не исчезнет, то прошу объяснить, как.
Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Объявляйте [динамический массив](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1138287/195342).

Comment: Динамический массив это хорошо, но я студент первого курса, и пока что подразумевается, что мы не знаем что такое динамические массивы и не можем ими пользоваться. Нельзя ли без них? Если нельзя, то окей, буду юзать динамический массив

Comment: Тогда используйте массив какого-то большого размера. У вас `n1` и `m1` имеют же какие-то разумные ограничения? Вот в них и работайте. Не больше 100 - значит, массив [100][100], примерно так...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdlib.h>
int main(){
printf("Введите размер первой матрицы. Если размер неизвестен, введите 0");
int n1,m1;
// опрашиваем размеры
scanf ("%d", &n1);
if (n1)
{
    scanf ("%d", &m1);
}
else 
{
    n1 = 100 ;
    m1 = 100 ;
}
// выделяем память под массив NxM
int ( * first_matrix ) [ m1 ] = malloc(sizeof(int[n1][m1]));
int i,j;
for (i=0; i<n1; i++) 
{
    for (j=0; j<m1; j++)
     scanf ("%d", &first_matrix[i][j]);
}
// освобождаем память
free(first_matrix);
}
```

или в стеке :

```
int first_matrix [ n1 ] [ m1 ] ;
```

освобождать память не надо.