# Как передать значения и размерность двумерного массива из одной функции в другую? (C++)

Tags: c++, функции, указатели

Нужно, чтобы функция передавала значения переменных размерности двумерного массива и его значения , чтобы эти значения могли бы использоваться в других функциях (простите за тавтологию). Я привёл фрагмент программы, где пользователю предлагается ввести размерность, а далее значения двумерного массива:

```
void arrayInput()
{
    int i, j, n, r;
    cout << "Set height and width of your array: ";
    cin >> n >> r;
    int ** m = new int *[n];
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        m[i] = new int[n];
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < r; j++)
        {
            cout << "m[" << i + 1 << "][" << j + 1 << "]= ";
            cin >> m[i][j];
        }

}
```

А эта функция нужна, чтобы вывести значения двумерного массива в виде таблицы:

```
void arrayOutputUnsort()
{
    arrayInput();
    cout << "Your array:" << endl;
    for (&i = 0; &i < &n; &i++)
    {
        for (&j = 0; &j < &r; &j++)
        {
            cout << &m[&i][&j] << "\t";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

Как правильно расставить в этой программе указатели?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Начнем с того, что у вас размеры-то разные... Так что в первой функции надо заменить

```
    m[i] = new int[n];
```

на

```
    m[i] = new int[r];
```

Далее, в вашем случае надо вернуть и массив, и размеры. Так что, наверное, имеет смысл такой код:

```
void arrayInput(int**&m, int&n, int&r)
{
    int i, j;
    cout << "Set height and width of your array: ";
    cin >> n >> r;
    m = new int *[n];
    .....
    // Дальше все как и раньше, у учетом замечания выше
```

И тогда

```
void arrayOutputUnsort()
{
    int ** m;
    int n,r;
    arrayInput(m,n,r);
    cout << "Your array:" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < r; j++)
        {
            cout << m[i][j] << "\t";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

P.S. Не понимаю, что вы хотели показать всеми этими `&`...

P.P.S. Но вообще-то вряд ли вы ограничитесь только выводом массива. В таком случае его надо создавать отдельно, и передавать в `arrayOutputUnsort()`, а не создавать его в этой функции.

P.P.P.S. Но лучше использовать, скажем, `vector<vector<int>>`, а то можете запутаться в указателях, рядом с которыми нужно еще и размеры передавать. Конечно, есть и другие варианты (например, почти Кама Сутра :) в этом [ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1138290/195342)), но раз у вас С++ — грех не воспользоваться его возможностями.