# Двумерный массив и очередной UB

Tags: c, массивы, указатели, память, инспекция-кода

В свое время дал на вопрос о двумерном массиве такой [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1138290/195342). Вчера дал на него ссылку в другом ответе. Но вчерашняя же дискуссия об UB при вычислении смещения поля в структуре (которое, хоть и считается официально UB, но мне таковым не кажется... но это мое личное мнение) заставила задуматься — не даю ли я некорректные в этой точки зрения советы?

Просто я стандарт, как прапорщик устав, наизусть не знаю, особенно в части особо тонких моментов с указателями, поэтому прошу гуру в <s>уставе</s>стандарте проверить этот код на корректность в плане UB. И если таковое имеет место, то помочь от него избавиться.

Итак, суперзадача — двумерный массив в С, который носит с собой свои размеры — *перед* указателем на данные, память под которые тоже выделяется одним куском: сначала массив указателей на строки, потом сами строки массива. Чтобы выделение-освобождение памяти было единственное, а передавать в разные функции можно было только один указатель.

Вот этот код (`T` — произвольный тип элементов массива, никак не параметр шаблона :) — напомню, это С).

```
T** create(int N, int M)
{
    T** arr = (T**)malloc(2*sizeof(int)+N*(sizeof(T*)+M*sizeof(T)));
    *((int*)arr)   = N;
    *((int*)arr+1) = M;
    arr = (T**)((char*)arr+2*sizeof(int));

    for(int i = N, ofs = N*sizeof(T*);
        i-->0; ofs += M*sizeof(T))
        arr[i] = (T*)((char*)arr + ofs);

    return arr;
}

void kill(T** arr)
{
    free((char*)arr-2*sizeof(int));
}

int rows(T**arr)
{
    return *(int*)((char*)arr-2*sizeof(int));
}

int cols(T**arr)
{
    return *(int*)((char*)arr-sizeof(int));
}
```

Практически-то все нормально, а вот теоретически как?

Comment: Не ответ на вопрос, но возможны проблемы с выравниванием. Например, при `N == 1, M == 1, sizeof(int) == 4, sizeof(T*) == 4, sizeof(T) == 8`. В C если указатель некорректно выравнен, то это UB. Доступ по невыровненным данным не требуется :)

Comment: @wololo Вот и хотелось бы получить и изучить :) код, который решает все эти проблемы...

Comment: На практике не сталкивался, но допускаю, что какой-нибудь `long double` на какой-нибудь архитектуре д.б. выровнен на 16. Я бы заложился на то, что malloc в такой архитектуре всегда возвращает максимальное выравнивание. Ну и тогда нужно первоначально выделить на 1 `T` больше и сдвинуть `arr` на нужное выравнивание (int N, M очевидно там поместятся). И тогда для работы `rows()`/`cols()` наверное придется запомнить это выравнивание в каком-нибудь статике при первом вызове `create_arr()`

Comment: @avp Хотелось бы посмотреть на живой код... Со всеми этими `_Alignas`...

Comment: @Harry, я подумал немного, получается, что желаемое  для архитектуры выравнивание надо все же держать в константах, в каком-нибудь .h, в принципе их можно вычислить, но надо будет делать несколько malloc и брать минимальную разницу в младших битах. Наверное это лучше сделать в configure (понимаю, что для SO-программ это плохой совет). Для простоты и надежности я бы ограничился 16 (если где-когда сломается, тогда и добавить нужный `ifdef`). / (Если сегодня будет время, то черкану примерчик с Alignes)

Comment: @avp Был бы признателен :)

Comment: Ну, решение проблем с выравниванием пока мне видеться [так](https://ideone.com/yfHdE4).

Comment: @wololo Не хотите оформить в виде ответа, дополнив пояснениями?...

Comment: @Harry, размер массива данных, наверно, всё же должен быть `N*M*sizeof(T)`…

Comment: @Fat-Zer А у меня он какой?...

Comment: @Harry, `M*sizeof(T)` — забыл на `N` домножить…

Comment: @Fat-Zer Посчитайте скобочки: `N*(sizeof(T*)+M*sizeof(T))`

Comment: @Harry, да, точно… я просто по-простому считал: 1 скобочка… 2 скобочка… много скобочек… =))

Comment: Все дружно рассматривают только выравнивание... А с какими-нибудь strict aliasing'ами все нормально?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Учитывая, что основное, что вызывает беспокойство — это корректное выравнивание выравнивание указателей и данных, то я бы сделал это как-то так:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdalign.h>


struct matrix_head {
  int N;
  int M;
  T *arr[];
};

struct matrix_head* arr2mh(T** arr) {
    return ((void*)arr - offsetof(struct matrix_head, arr));
}

T** create(int N, int M) {
    // Размер заголовка матрицы вместе с массивом указателей
    size_t matrix_head_sz = sizeof(struct matrix_head)+N*sizeof(T);
    // Маска выравнивания например для alignof(T)==16 => 0x0..00f
    const unsigned long align_mask = alignof(T)-1;
    // Вычисление, сколько потребуется дополнительного паддинга,
    // чтобы получить корректное выравнивание для массива данных.
    size_t data_padding = matrix_head_sz & align_mask ?
                          alignof(T) - (matrix_head_sz & align_mask) : 0;

    struct matrix_head* mh = malloc( matrix_head_sz + data_padding + N*M*sizeof(T) );
    mh->N = N;
    mh->M = M;

    T* data = (void*)mh + matrix_head_sz + data_padding;

    for(int i = 0; i<N; i++) {
        mh->arr[i] = data + i*M;
    }

    return mh->arr;
}

void kill(T** arr)
{
    free(arr2mh(arr));
}

int rows(T**arr)
{
    return arr2mh(arr)->N;
}

int cols(T**arr)
{
    return arr2mh(arr)->M;
}
```

Замечания:

- Код не отлаживался и может содержать ошибки
- Гибкие массивы-члены (*Flexible array member*) — часть стандарта со времён C99, но AFAIK как расширение поддерживались компиляторами (как минимум, gcc и msvc) и раньше; для древних компиляторов можно использовать `arr[0]` или `arr[1]`; в последнем случае единичку из `sizeof()` придётся вычитать вручную.
- Компилятор сам заботится о выравнивании массива указателей в такой структуре
- Выравнивание массива данных придётся делать вручную
- `alignof()` добавлен только в C11
- `offsetof()` в стандарте со времён царя Гороха
- Мне не нравится использование ненужного массива указателей: я бы убрал его и использовал бы для адресации либо макросы (через `i*M+j`), либо VLA, но раз такая структура данных в ТЗ, то кто я такой, чтобы с этим спорить…

Comment: Только imho надо вот так -- `align_mask = ~(alignof(T) - 1)` (и далее аналогично). Поскольку, например, alignof(double) == 8, а alignof(int) == 4

Comment: @avp, да, спасибо, я что-то перемудрил...

Answer (score 2):

К сожалению, препроцессор не знает значений `sizeof`, поэтому предполагаем, что int занимает 4 байта.

Тогда, с учетом того, что для обеспечения выравнивания данных после массива указателей в общем объеме выделенной памяти возможно придется добавить дополнительный промежуток, получается что-то в таком духе

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#if Arch1
#define ALI 4
#elif Arch2
#define ALI 64
#elif Arch3
#define ALI 32
#endif

#ifndef ALI  
#define ALI 16
#endif

// в предположении, что sizeof(int) == 4
#if ALI < 8
#undef ALI
#define ALI (2 * sizeof(int))
#endif

T **
create_a (int N, int M)
{
  printf("create_a: ALI %d\n", (int)ALI);
  // такое количество памяти нужно под указатели на строки и pad для выравнивания данных на ALI
  size_t data_ofs = (N * sizeof(T *) + ALI - 1) & ~(ALI - 1);
  int *d = malloc(ALI + data_ofs + N * M * sizeof(T));

  if (!d)
    return 0;
  d[0] = N, d[1] = M;

  printf("malloc = %p\n", d);
  return (T**)((char *)d + ALI);
}


T **
create_array (int N, int M)
{
  T **arr = create_a(N, M);
  if (!arr)
    return 0;

  for (int i = 0, ofs = (N * sizeof(T *) + ALI - 1) & ~(ALI - 1);
       i < N;
       i++, ofs += M * sizeof(T))
    arr[i] = (T*)((char*)arr + ofs);

  return arr;
}


void
kill_a (T **a)
{
  free((void *)a - ALI);
}

int
rows_a (T **a)
{
  int *d = (void *)a - ALI; 
  return d[0];
}

int
cols_a (T **a)
{
  int *d = (void *)a - ALI;
  return d[1];
}


int
main ()
{
  printf("T sizeof: %ld\n", sizeof(T));

  T **arr;
  printf("arr ptrs: %p\n", arr = create_array(N, M));
  printf("rows: %d  cols: %d\n", rows_a(arr), cols_a(arr));
  kill_a(arr);
    
  return puts("End") == EOF;
}
```

Результаты запусков

```
avp@avp-desktop:~/avp/hashcode$ gcc ttt.c -DT='long double' -DArch1
avp@avp-desktop:~/avp/hashcode$ ./a.out
T sizeof: 16
create_a: ALI 8
malloc = 0x7f4eb3e49010
arr ptrs: 0x7f4eb3e49018
rows: 100  cols: 200
End
avp@avp-desktop:~/avp/hashcode$ gcc ttt.c -DT='long double' -DArch3
avp@avp-desktop:~/avp/hashcode$ 
avp@avp-desktop:~/avp/hashcode$ ./a.out
T sizeof: 16
create_a: ALI 32
malloc = 0x7ff0539a5010
arr ptrs: 0x7ff0539a5030
rows: 100  cols: 200
End
avp@avp-desktop:~/avp/hashcode$ gcc ttt.c -DT='long double'
avp@avp-desktop:~/avp/hashcode$ ./a.out
T sizeof: 16
create_a: ALI 16
malloc = 0x7fae10586010
arr ptrs: 0x7fae10586020
rows: 100  cols: 200
End
avp@avp-desktop:~/avp/hashcode$
```

Comment: А почему вы рассматриваете проблемы с выравниванием размеров массива, но не рассматриваете вторую часть — массив указателей и массив данных? Почему тут все получается хорошо автоматически?...

Comment: Думаю, что с выравниванием указателей в выделенной памяти проблем нет (мы же сами это только что сделали), а вот насчет данных после них..., я как-то упустил этот момент. Да, видимо надо поправить так, чтобы выравнивание данных внутри области также всегда соответствовало величине `ALI`, независимо от sizeof уазателя.

Comment: А как будет/может проявляться несоответствие выравниваний в реальной программе? Какими сбоями это чревато? И еще - а как с массивами получается? Когда мы просто используем `malloc(N*sizeof(T))` — где гарантия, что выравнивание будет именно то, что надо? Особенно если учесть, что, насколько я помню, гарантируется, что в массиве данные без единого просвета, как генеральские погоны :)

Comment: Несоответствие выравниванию может вызвать bus error (или замедление работы). Гарантию при `malloc(N*sizeof(T))` дает сам malloc, память должна быть выровнена для любого типа. Т.е. у нас получается, если `ofs = malloc(N*sizeof(T *))` не кратен ALI (это надо считать до вызова malloc), то к запрошенной памяти надо добавить эту дельту (и к ofs тоже. Т.е. `ofs = N * sizeof(T *) + delta)`)