# Ошибка core dumped

Tags: c

При вводе в статический двумерный массив [2000][2000] программа выводит core dumped. ;(
Вот программа(Си):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void) {
  FILE *input = fopen("input.txt", "rt");
  FILE *output = fopen("output.txt", "wt");
  //j = x, i = y;
  long int size = 0, k = 0, MAX = 0, dec = 0;
  fscanf(input, "%li", &size);
  long int pole[size][size];
  for (int i=0;i<size;i++){
    for (int j=0;j<size;j++){
      fscanf(input, "%li", &pole[j][i]);
      //fprintf(output, "%d ", pole[i][j]);
      //k++;
      //if (k==size){fprintf(output, "\n");}
    }
  }
  if (size == 1){fprintf(output, "%d", (int)pole[0][0]); exit(0);}
  if (size == 0){fprintf(output, "0"); exit(0);}
  
  for (int i=0;i<size;i++){
    for (int j=0;j<size;j++){
      
      
      if (i==0){
        if (j==0){
          if (pole[j][i]+pole[j+1][i]+pole[j][i+1]>MAX){
          MAX=pole[j][i]+pole[j+1][i]+pole[j][i+1];}}
        
        if (j==size-1){
          if (pole[size-1][i]+pole[size-2][i]+pole[size-1][i+1]>MAX){MAX=pole[size-1][i]+pole[size-2][i]+pole[size-1][i+1];}}
        
        if ((j!=0)&&(j!=size-1)){
          if (pole[j][i]+pole[j-1][i]+pole[j][i+1]>MAX){
            MAX = pole[j][i]+pole[j-1][i]+pole[j][i+1];
          }
          if (pole[j][i]+pole[j-1][i]+pole[j+1][i]>MAX){
            MAX = pole[j][i]+pole[j-1][i]+pole[j+1][i];
          }
          if (pole[j][i]+pole[j+1][i]+pole[j][i+1]>MAX){
            MAX = pole[j][i]+pole[j+1][i]+pole[j][i+1];
          }}
      }    
      
    
    
    if (j==0){ 
      if (i==0){
        if (pole[j][i]+pole[j+1][i]+pole[j][i+1]>MAX){
          MAX=pole[j][i]+pole[j+1][i]+pole[j][i+1];}}
        
      if (i==size-1){
          if (pole[j][size-1]+pole[j][size-2]+pole[j+1][size-1]>MAX){MAX=pole[j][size-1]+pole[j][size-2]+pole[j+1][size-1];}}
        
      if ((i!=0)&&(i!=size-1)){ 
        if (pole[j][i]+pole[j][i-1]+pole[j+1][i]>MAX){
          MAX = pole[j][i]+pole[j][i-1]+pole[j+1][i];
        }
        if (pole[j][i]+pole[j][i-1]+pole[j][i+1]>MAX){
          MAX = pole[j][i]+pole[j][i-1]+pole[j][i+1];
        }
        if (pole[j][i]+pole[j+1][i]+pole[j][i+1]>MAX){
          MAX = pole[j][i]+pole[j+1][i]+pole[j][i+1];
        }}
    }
    
    
    if (j==size-1){
      if (i==0){if (pole[size-1][i]+pole[size-2][i]+pole[size-1][i+1]     >MAX){MAX=pole[size-1][i]+pole[size-2][i]+pole[size-1][i+1];}} 
      if (i==size-1){if (pole[size-1][size-1]+pole[size-2][size-1]+pole[size-1][size-2]>MAX){MAX=pole[size-1][size-1]+pole[size-2][size-1]+pole[size-1][size-2];}}
      
      if ((i!=0)&&(i!=size-1)){ 
        if (pole[j][i]+pole[j][i-1]+pole[j-1][i]>MAX){
          MAX = pole[j][i]+pole[j][i-1]+pole[j-1][i];
        }
        if (pole[j][i]+pole[j][i-1]+pole[j][i+1]>MAX){
          MAX = pole[j][i]+pole[j][i-1]+pole[j][i+1];
        }
        if (pole[j][i]+pole[j][i+1]+pole[j-1][i]>MAX){
          MAX = pole[j][i]+pole[j][i+1]+pole[j-1][i];
        }}
    }
    

    if (i==size-1){
      if (j==0){if (pole[j][size-1]+pole[j][size-2]+pole[j+1][size-1]>MAX){MAX=pole[j][size-1]+pole[j][size-2]+pole[j+1][size-1];}}
      
      if (j==size-1){if (pole[size-1][size-1]+pole[size-2][size-1]+pole[size-1][size-2]>MAX){MAX=pole[size-1][size-1]+pole[size-2][size-1]+pole[size-1][size-2];}}
      
      if ((j!=0)&&(j!=size-1)){
          if (pole[j][size-1]+pole[j-1][size-1]+pole[j+1][size-1]>MAX){
            MAX = pole[j][size-1]+pole[j-1][size-1]+pole[j+1][size-1];
          }
          if (pole[j][size-1]+pole[j-1][size-1]+pole[j][size-2]>MAX){
            MAX = pole[j][size-1]+pole[j-1][size-1]+pole[j][size-2];
          }
          if (pole[j][size-1]+pole[j+1][size-1]+pole[j][size-2]>MAX){
            MAX = pole[j][size-1]+pole[j+1][size-1]+pole[j][size-2];
          }
        }
      }
    
    if ((i!=0)&&(i!=size-1)&&(j!=0)&&(j!=size-1)){
      if (pole[j][i]+pole[j-1][i]+pole[j+1][i]>MAX){
        MAX = pole[j][i]+pole[j-1][i]+pole[j+1][i];
      }
      if (pole[j][i]+pole[j][i-1]+pole[j][i+1]>MAX){
        MAX = pole[j][i]+pole[j][i-1]+pole[j][i+1];
      }
      if (pole[j][i]+pole[j-1][i]+pole[j][i-1]>MAX){
        MAX = pole[j][i]+pole[j-1][i]+pole[j][i-1];
      }
      if (pole[j][i]+pole[j-1][i]+pole[j][i+1]>MAX){
        MAX = pole[j][i]+pole[j-1][i]+pole[j][i+1];
      }
      if (pole[j][i]+pole[j+1][i]+pole[j][i-1]>MAX){
        MAX = pole[j][i]+pole[j+1][i]+pole[j][i-1];
      }
      if (pole[j][i]+pole[j+1][i]+pole[j][i+1]>MAX){
        MAX = pole[j][i]+pole[j+1][i]+pole[j][i+1];
      }
    } 
  }}
  if (MAX>2000000000){
    dec=MAX/1000000000;
    MAX = MAX%1000000000;
    fprintf(output, "%d", (int)dec);
    fprintf(output, "%d", (int)MAX);
    } else {

  fprintf(output, "%d", (int)MAX);}
  
  return 0;}
```

Comment: А размер стека какой? Подозреваю, что меньше 16 МБ, на которые ваша программа рассчитывает.

Answer (score 2):

Посмотрим:

```
long int pole[size][size];
```

Итого требуется 2000*2000 элементов по 4 байта (если не 8 — какой размер `long int` у вас?), т.е. примерно 15.3 МБайт. Обычно стек имеет куда меньший размер.

Так что лучше вам организовать этот массив как динамический, воспользовавшись, например, советами [отсюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1138290/195342).