# ошибка при вызове процедуры си [Error] cannot convert 'int*' to 'int**' for argument '2' to 'void sum(int, int**, int**, int**)'

Tags: c, массивы, функции, динамические-массивы, процедуры

Составить и отладить программу вычисления матрицы F по заданным матрицам A, B и С размера n*n. Матричные операции реализовать в виде отдельных подпрограмм.
C х A + A х C х B

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

//расчет формулы F = C*A + A*C*B

//void sum(int**, int**, int**, int);

int multAC(int **A, int **C, int n) // Функция для расчета C*A
{

    int F1[n][n];
    int i, j;
    
    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for (j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            F1[i][j] = A[i][j] * C[i][j];
            return F1[i][j];
        }
    }
    
    

}

int multABC(int **A, int **B, int **C, int n) // Функция для расчета C*A*B
{

    int F2[n][n];
    int i, j;
    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for (j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            F2[i][j] = A[i][j] * B[i][j] * C[i][j];
            return F2[i][j];
        }
    }

    
}

void sum(int n, int **A, int **B, int **C) // Функция для расчета F
{
    

    int F[n][n];
    int F1[n][n], F2[n][n];

    int i, j;   
    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for (j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            //F[i][j] = F1[i][j] + F2[i][j];
            F[i][j] = multAC(A, C, n) + multABC(A, B, C, n);
        }
    }
    
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j<n; j++)
        {
            printf("%d\t", F[i][j]);    
        }
        printf("\n");
    }   
    
    
}


int main()
{
    int n;
    srand(time(NULL));
    
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"");
    printf("Введите размер матрицы n: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    
    int A[n][n], B[n][n], C[n][n];
    int i,j;
    for (i=0;i<n;i++) //генерация массивов
    {
        for (j=0; j<n; j++)
        {
            A[i][j] = 0 + rand() % 100;
            B[i][j] = 0 + rand() % 100;
            C[i][j] = 0 + rand() % 100;
                
        }
    }
        
    for (i=0; i<n; i++) //вывод массива А
    {
        for (j=0; j<n; j++)
        {
            printf("%d\t", A[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
   
    printf("\n\n");
    
    for (i=0; i<n; i++) //вывод массива В
    {
        for (j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            printf("%d\t", B[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
   
    printf("\n\n");

    for (i=0; i<n; i++) //вывод массива С
    {
        for (j=0; j<n; j++)
        {
            printf("%d\t", C[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    
    sum(n, *A, *B, *C); //вызов процедуры
 
    
}
```

Comment: А вопрос в чем? :)

Comment: Какая ошибка то? Всё должно быть написано в вопросе.

Comment: исправила, извините @DmitryK

Comment: исправила, извините @CrazyElf

Comment: Типы `int a[][]` и `int ** a` — это *совершенно разные типы*, передавать один вместо другого в функцию нельзя!

Comment: @Harry тут как раз вопрос в том, что я не понимаю как правильно передать

Comment: `return F1[i][j];` стоит в цикле. Т.е. функция прервется после одного умножения

Comment: Создавайте двумерные массивы динамически, как `int**a`. Посмотрите этот вопрос — https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1138287/195342

Comment: У вас собственное понимание перемножения матриц? или вам нужно алгебраическое перемножение матриц? Просто по правилам алгебры, у матриц строки умножаются на столбцы, а Вы умножаете строки на строки.

Comment: @DmitryK , оййййййййййй
Давно проходили, призабыла

Comment: Для начала вам следует избавиться ото всех двухуровневых C массивов. Так как `n` задается во время выполнения тут сделает создавать исключительно динамические массивы из n * n элементов.