# Почему после добавления вывода строки ошибка исчезла?

Tags: c, матрицы, malloc, segmentation-fault

Моя программа создает матрицу (размер из аргументов командной строки), заполняет ее и печатает:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int **matrix_maker(int lines, int colons)
/*Функция создает матрицу. Внутри функции проблема*/
{
        int **tmp = NULL;
/*Без следующей ЧУДОСТРОКИ программа отказывается работать*/
        printf("%d\n", 1);

        tmp = (int**)malloc(lines*sizeof(int*) + lines*colons*sizeof(int));
        for(int i = 0; i < lines; ++i){
                *(tmp+i) = (int*)(tmp+colons*(i+1));
        }
        return tmp;
}

int str_to_unsigned_int(const char *str)
/*Функция превращает строку в число (для аргументов командной строки)*/
{
        int num = 0;
        for(; *str; ++str){
                if( (*str)<'0' || (*str)>'9' ){
                        fprintf(stderr, "Not a number\n");
                        return -1;
                }
                num = num*10 + (*str)-'0';
        }
        return num;
}

void matrix_filler(int **matrix, int lines, int colons)
/*Функция заполняет матрицу (Чем именно - не важно, программа учебная)*/
{
        for(int i = 0; i < lines; i++)
                for(int j = 0; j < colons; j++){
                        matrix[i][j] = (lines*i+colons*j+i*j)/lines+colons;
                }
}

void matrix_printer(int **matrix, int lines, int colons)
/*Функция печатает матрицу*/
{
        for(int i = 0; i < lines; i++){
                for(int j = 0; j < colons; j++){
                        printf("%d ", matrix[i][j]);
                }
                printf("\n");
        }
}


int main(int argc, const char **argv)
{
        if(argc < 3){
                fprintf(stderr, "To few arguments\n");
                return 1;
        }

        int lines;
        int colons;
        lines = str_to_unsigned_int(*(argv+1));
        colons = str_to_unsigned_int(*(argv+2));
        if(lines == -1 || colons == -1){
                return 2;
        }

        int **matrix = NULL;

        matrix = matrix_maker(lines, colons);
        matrix_filler(matrix, lines, colons);
        matrix_printer(matrix, lines, colons);

        return 0;

}
```

В этой программе есть функция `matrix_maker`, которая собственно **создает** матрицу `int`-ов размером `lines` на `colons`. Чтобы не вызывать функцию `malloc` много раз (`lines+1`, если быть точным), я резервирую память сразу под матрицу нужного размера один раз, а потом просто заполняю первые `lines` ячеек указателями на строки матрицы.

А тепер **вопрос**:
Почему без `ЧУДОСТРОКИ` вывод моей функции (в терминале при запуске программы):

```
malloc(): corrupted top size
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Но если я просто вставлю мою отладочною `ЧУДОСТРОКУ`, то функция выводит в терминале:

```
1 /*Это та единица, которую печатает ЧУДОСТРОКА*/
12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 
13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 
14 15 16 17 18 19 21 22 23 24 25 26 
15 16 17 18 20 21 22 23 25 26 27 28 
16 17 18 20 21 22 24 25 26 28 29 30 
17 18 19 21 22 24 25 26 28 29 31 32 
18 19 21 22 24 25 27 28 30 31 33 34 
19 20 22 23 25 26 28 30 31 33 34 36 
20 21 23 25 26 28 30 31 33 35 36 38 
21 22 24 26 28 29 31 33 35 36 38 40 
22 23 25 27 29 31 33 34 36 38 40 42 
23 24 26 28 30 32 34 36 38 40 42 44
```

***Как так, и чего я не понимаю?***

Comment: С памятью конечно кавардак, однако за исключением `puts("before malloc");` эта функция вряд ли что-то выводит, тем более, что выделенный массив по большей части остается неинициализированным. А для создания матрицы достаточно сделать одномерный массив из `lines` x `colons` элементов.

Comment: @user7860670,  Читать внимательно: **ПРОГРАММА** создает, заполняет и выводит матрицу. В программе есть **ФУНКЦИЯ**, которая собственоо **создает** матрицу.

Одномерные массив? А как тогда обратися к `n`-ому елементу второй строки?

Comment: Читать внимательно: (цитата) "Не если я просто вставлю мою отладочною ЧУДОСТРОКУ, то  **функция выводит** в терминале:" Собственно вопрос под закрытие, так как отсутствует [mcve]

Comment: @user7860670, спасибо, поправил, там "НО")

Comment: @user7860670, При вставке "отладочной" `puts()` функция работает, и к `j` елементу `i` строки можно обратися как `matrix[i][j]`. Но как только я уберу функцию `puts()`, то программа выдает `currupted top size`. Почему так??? 
Вот мой вопрос, и я не понимаю, почему Вы хотите его закрыть!

Comment: Я же написал почему - в вопросе отсутствует [минимальный воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Здесь телепатов нет, и чего там еще происходит в вашей программе - никому не известно. Задавайте вопрос и добавляйте в него код только после того, как проблема локализована и воспроизводится не только у вас. И еще лучше сразу добавить ссылку на онлайн компилятор, чтоб читающим было проще.

Comment: @user7860670, Сделал "Минимальный воспроизводимый пример".

Comment: VC++ — эффект не воспроизводится...

Comment: @Harry, Что это значит, я Вас не понимаю. (Это может быть связано с тем, что я только учусь)

Comment: Значит, что выводится все нормально что так, что эдак... Но меня смущает размещение вашей структуры в памяти. У вас какое приложение (32 или 64-разрядное)?

Comment: @Harry Я создавал учебную программу, которая делает матрицу одним `malloc`-ом (через адресную арифметику). Потом заполняет ее, а потом печатает. Система разрядности 64. Компилирую через `gcc`. Какая разрядность приложения на выходе - я не знаю(.
У меня есть разница вывода "что так, что эдак". ПОЧЕМУ? (в этом и вопрос, ведь сама функция `printf` ничего не меняет.)

Comment: Она может немножко смещать размещение данных в стеке, и этого окажется достаточно, чтобы **при введенных вами аргументах** затирание памяти было не фатальным... У вас в любом случае неверная работа с памятью, а это может приводить к очень забавным эффектам, которые проявляются в том числе очень далеко от места ошибки... Ответ, где у вас ошибка, я дал. Про разрядность я спрашивал потому, что при 32-разрядном приложении и colons == lines ошибка вообще не будет себя проявлять...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Смотрим сюда:

```
tmp = (int**)malloc(lines*sizeof(int*) + lines*colons*sizeof(int));
```

Т.е. выделено вначале место под `lines` указателей, а потом

```
for(int i = 0; i < lines; ++i){
        *(tmp+i) = (int*)(tmp+colons*(i+1));
}
```

вы их расставляете... Но давайте посмотрим, куда смотрит первый же указатель:

```
*tmp = (int*)(tmp + colons);
```

А должен? Как минимум на место после `lines` указателей, т.е.

```
*tmp = (int*)(tmp + lines);
```

Вы просто неверно написали работу с памятью...

Посмотрите вот этот [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1138290/195342), часть, начинающуюся со слов

> Еще один вариант - выделение одним большим куском, чтобы и освобождать один раз. При этом вначале хранятся указатели на строки, а затем - данные.

Видите отличие моего кода от вашего?...

Вот так будет правильнее:

```
int ** tmp = malloc(lines*(sizeof(int*)+colons*sizeof(int)));
for(int i = 0, ofs = lines*sizeof(int*); i < lines; i++)
    tmp[i] = (int*)((char*)tmp + ofs + i*colons*sizeof(int));
```

Comment: Спасибо, тепер я понял, что у меня `*(tmp+i) = (int*)(tmp+colons*(i+1));` указывал не на марицу, а на часть себя. Понятно стало так же и то, что сдвиг по стоке указателей нужно делать на размер указателя (у меня 8), а по матрице на размер `sizeof(int)*colon`. Но ведь размер `int` у меня 4, а значит нужно привести `tmp` к `char*` и к нему добавить нужное смещение. Спасибо еще раз, вроди бы прояснилось чуток.)

Comment: Обычно помогает нарисовать схему размещения в памяти на бумажке и провести все нужные стрелочки, расписать смещения...

Answer (score 2):

Задумка понятна - выделить один буфер для `lines` указателей, за которым идут `lines` x `colons` значений, затем дать указателям указывать на соотв. строку.
Смещение нулевого указателя в буфере должно быть `sizeof(int *) * lines` байт, первого `sizeof(int *) * lines + sizeof(int) * colons`, второго - `sizeof(int *) * lines + sizeof(int) * colons * 2`.

Рассмотрим, что происходит на строке `*(tmp+i) = (int*)(tmp+colons*(i+1));`. Смещение нулевого указателя будет `sizeof(int *) * colons * 1` байт, первого - `sizeof(int *) * colons * 2` байт, второго - `sizeof(int *) * colons * 3` байт. Как видно, значения указателей начинают разезжаться с самого начала, а потом и вовсе выходят за пределы буфера (подразумевая 64-битный указатель), что при обращении к ним выливается в чтение за пределами буфера, что является Неопределенным Поведением.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ и за "минимальный воспроизводимый пример". С арифметикой тоже чутка разобрался)