# Как переместить элементы одного массива в другой

Tags: c, массивы, указатели

Задание:Дана действительная квадратная матрица порядка k. Преобразовать матрицу по следующему
правилу: строку с номером k сделать столбцом с номером k, а столбец с номером k — строкой с
номером k.
Создал вроде два массива, но не могу перекидывать из одного в другой элементы. В момент приравнивания, программа останавливается и пишет "Исключение не обработано"

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>
int main()
{
    int** mas;
    int M, N;
    int** mas1;

    printf("ryad pls:");
    scanf_s("%d", &M);
    printf("stob pls:");
    scanf_s("%d", &N);
    mas1 = (int**)malloc(M * N* sizeof(int));
    mas = (int**)malloc(M * N * sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            printf("arrayl (%d)(%d) = ", i, j);
            scanf_s("%d", &mas[i * N + j]);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            printf("%5d ", mas[i * N + j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
    {

        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            if (j != N - 1)

                mas1[j][i] = mas[i][j];
            else
                mas1[j][i] = mas[i][j];

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Мне кажется вы надергали кода из разных кусочков не понимая как он работает?) Или в чем причина разного способа обращения к массиву?) Сначала как к одномерному высчитывая индекс, а затем как к двумерному..... ```mas[i * N + j] => mas[i][j]```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обращение

```
 mas1[j][i] = mas[i][j]
```

категорически неверное! При вашем объявлении массивов как `int**`, при том что реально они таковыми не являются!

Вот [исправленный код](https://ideone.com/z2gk7r), посмотрите сами, что изменено, и подумайте, почему...

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>
int main()
{
    int* mas;
    int M, N;
    int* mas1;

    printf("ryad pls:");
    scanf_s("%d", &M);
    printf("stob pls:");
    scanf_s("%d", &N);

    if (M != N) {
        printf("It's not **SQUARE** matrix!\n");
        return 1;
    }

    mas1 = malloc(M * N* sizeof(int));
    mas = malloc(M * N * sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            printf("arrayl (%d)(%d) = ", i, j);
            scanf_s("%d", &mas[i*N + j]);
        }
    }

    printf("\n\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            printf("%5d ", mas[i*N + j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("\n\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
            mas1[j*M+i] = mas[i*N+j];

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < M; j++)
        {
            printf("%5d ", mas1[i*M + j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

}
```

Кстати, советую посмотреть вот этот вопрос: [Создание динамического двумерного массива](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1138287/195342).

Comment: примерно понял, спасибо. Но почему **int не правильно? Мне все-равно пришлось  добавить звезды, а так же перед malloc добавить (**int), тк он жаловался, что массив типа void

Comment: Начну с конца. Перед `malloc`вам пришлось добавить приведение типа, потому что вы *компилировали этот код как **С++**, а **не как С***. Если компилировать код как С (например, для начала дайте файлу расширение .c), то это приведение лишнее. Далее, `int**` предусматривает, что в элементах `mas[i]` лежат *не данные*, а **указатели на строки данных**. У вас такие указатели лежат по адресу `mas[0]`, `mas[1]` и так далее? Нет? Вот вам и ответ! Еще раз *настоятельно* прошу просмотреть вопрос и ответы по ссылке в конце приведенного выше ответа!