# Не показывает cout в c++

Tags: c++, циклы

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int **house = new int*[3];
    house[12] = new int[12];
    int sum;
    for(int p = 0; p < 3; p++)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
        {
            cout << "Enter the price: ";
            cin >> house[p][i];
            sum = sum + house[p][i];
        }
    }
    cout << endl << "Summary: " << sum << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Здравствуйте, я написал этот код который просит вести цены дом в течении 3 год и оно потом должна вывести сумму цен домов, ну я написал как надо и хочу чтобы она показала сумму но не показывает, а в чем может быть проблема? Заранее спасибо за помощь

Comment: Ну вы же массив создали неверно... Посмотрите этот вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1138287/195342   Кстати, и `sum` у вас и вовсе не инициализирована...

Comment: @Harry Спасибо большое

Answer (score 0, accepted):

а не проще ли сделать так:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main () {
int i=0,j=0;
int array[3][12]={};
int sum=0;
for( j=0;j<3;j++){
for( i=0;i<12;i++){
   cout<<"Enter the price from "<<j+1<<" year "<<i+1<<" month: " ; cin>>array[j][i]; }}


for( j=0;j<3;j++){
for( i=0;i<12;i++){
   sum=sum+array[j][i];   }}
cout<<"summary: "<<sum;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь но я подумал тип зачем мне указатель и сделал простую переменную, и еще забыл про инициализацию переменной sum

Comment: бывает, сам когда-то только начинал...

Comment: ну и да думаю, что если вы знаете что пользователь введет число, то корректней сформировать массив целочисленных значений, как у меня в 6 строке